# Generate the same PBKDF2 keys in C# and NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, pbkdf2

I'm trying to generate the same password hash using NodeJS crypto library and C# Rfc2898DeriveBytes. The C# implementation doesn't generate the same key when using the salt generated from NodeJs. What am I doing wrong?

The salt and hash generated in nodeJS:

```
Salt: GJNw/wzXZxEdXrheqo322mf0x+92AeAuAHH48iiGZ+A=
Hash: w6fCpsKxw78Fw4pMFk5Zw6vDin7CnG5VwpUWBSjCo8OSOTJ6w47Cv8KWcjIpwoA=
```

The hash generated in C#:

```
1G84mPkY78nsQ2BzO/qUPd+e0Lobrz7ZLzc+p7Zh0o8=
```

My C# test code is as follows:

```
public const int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 32; 
public const int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;

public static string HashPassword(string password, string salt)
        {
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

            var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS);
            var hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(HASH_BYTE_SIZE);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string salt = "GJNw/wzXZxEdXrheqo322mf0x+92AeAuAHH48iiGZ+A=";
            string plainTextPsw = "12345";

            string hashedPsw = PasswordHash.HashPassword(plainTextPsw, salt);

            Console.WriteLine(hashedPsw);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And NodeJs:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var iterations = 1000;
var bytes = 32;

exports.createSalt = function () {
    return new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(bytes)).toString('base64');
}

exports.hash = function hash(text, salt, callback) {
    crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes, function (err, derivedKey) {
        if (err) { callback(err); }
        else {
            var h = new Buffer(derivedKey).toString('base64');
            callback(null, h);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Include the result of the C# version.

Comment: Sure, C# generates: 1G84mPkY78nsQ2BzO/qUPd+e0Lobrz7ZLzc+p7Zh0o8=

Comment: See my updated answer for solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bad conversions occurring in the Node.js code that produce an invalid result.

First, the "salt" passed to the pbkdf2 function should be the random bytes, without any transformation applied. However, in this case, the bytes are encoded with Base64 to text, and the characters in that text are used by Node.js as the salt.

Then, the derived key should be encoded directly to text with Base64. But here, the bytes of the key are treated as characters; this character string is converted to a new string of different bytes using UTF-8 encoding. This encoding is then encoded with Base64 to produce the final, incorrect result.

Comment: Ok. So I've tried again with key length of 256. The output is: 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